# Pyserial serial.write() doesn't work

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I need to communicate with an Arduino. Doing `serial.readline()` to read what Arduino has to say works fine. Doing `serial.write('something')` doesn't seem to do anything.

What is interesting is that if I write the same code in the console or command-line, it works as expected...

Using Python 2.7.

Python code:

```
import time
import serial

# setup Arduino USB communication
try:
    arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial('com3', 9600)

except: # not connected/damaged
    pass

while True:
    if arduinoSerialData.inWaiting() > 0:
        arduinoSerialData.write('A')
        arduinoSerialData.flush()
        datastr = arduinoSerialData.readline()
        print datastr
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: this does not include any information that we would need to help you. Be more specific on what is not working and post any code that could help us.

Comment: did you try `.flush()`

Comment: Doesn't flush() freeze the program? My program has a main loop. I'll update the post with a code.

Comment: flush will clear the buffer

Comment: If you don't have flow-control disabled, then pyserial could be vainly waiting for CTS to be active.

Comment: Okay, I posted the code. What is written doesnt get printed. See if you can notice a mistake.

Comment: Patrick, I don't know what that is.

Comment: @LeoErvin, CTS -> clear to send

Comment: Nevermind, your code shows you haven't set it on.  Have you used a terminal program, e.g. putty, to send 'A' characters, and does it do what you expect?  (It's useful to try to isolate the problem to pyserial or something else.)

Comment: So your arduino will send stuff unprovoked?  Because the code you posted will not send an 'A' until it sees some data come back.

Comment: What does CTS do and how do I activate it? Arduino also sends strings, yeah, but it has to? Why?

Comment: No, you don't have CTS hooked up, and by default pyserial is not looking at it, so chances are that flow control is not your issue.  By "unprovoked" I mean that it starts sending strings without you doing anything on the computer end.  If that doesn't happen, your program won't send anything because it waits until it sees receive characters before sending the "A".

Comment: When you say your data isn't going out, have you dropped a scope on the line, or are you relying on the arduino telling you that?

Comment: I'm saying that because I print a serial.readline() after I do serial.write() and it doesn't show what I've written. BTW, what does "dropped a scope on the line" mean?

Comment: I meant look at the output line with an oscilloscope.  Even if the arduino is echoing everything you send, readline() won't give you anything until it sees a line (e.g. a carriage return and/or linefeed), and you won't get that if you are only sending 'A' characters.

Comment: Man I don't have an oscilloscope... A question , is what gets written by Arduino and the PC program separate from each other? (In other words, can I read what I wrote to Serial with Python from Python?). From my tests it seems like they are separate/independent. BTW, I tried sending strings with newlines too.

Comment: Okay this is probably important: if I type the same Python code in the console, it works, lights blink. It doesn't work when executed as a file.

Comment: Perhaps when executed from the program, your loop sends the 'A' character before the arduino has finished sending the line, whereas when you do it from the command line, perhaps the the data has already been received before you send the 'A' character.  You might experiment with, for example, doing the `write()` after the `readline()`.

Comment: I actually stripped down the program to only have the write(). Still same issue. Only way to make it ''work'' is to do time.sleep(2) before write(), but that completely cripples the program, on top of that makes it blink, not be on continuously.

Answer (score 4):

Put a `time.sleep(2)` line after you open the port to give the Arduino time to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I know I´m a little bit too late but today I had the same problem with Pyserial and an ESP32, a device sort of like an arduino. The solution was to give pyserial the same configuration as the serial interface in the ESP32:

```
esp = serial.Serial("COM10", 115200)
esp.parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN
esp.stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
esp.bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
```

I send the commands like this:

```
arr = [32,2,0,4] #Decimal
esp.write(arr)
```

This is the ESP32 configuration, in case you need to know:

```
uart_config_t uart_config = {
        .baud_rate = 115200,
        .data_bits = UART_DATA_8_BITS,
        .parity    = UART_PARITY_EVEN,
        .stop_bits = UART_STOP_BITS_1,
        .flow_ctrl = UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_DISABLE
};
    
uart_param_config(UART_PORT_NUM, &uart_config);
```

The ESP now echoes the command correctly I hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

try to add the timeout parameter in the Python script, then try to set your main arduino code in a while loop
step1: python

```
 arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial('com3', 9600, 1)
```

replace the  arduinoSerialData.flush() by:

```
 arduinoSerialData.flushInput()
```

step2: Arduino:

```
void loop(){
    while (Serial.available > 0){
            // your main code
    }
}
```

Comment: I also use the arduino to tell the state of 6 buttons, which I'd like to check every 0.5 seconds. WIll that be an issue with this solution?

Comment: Yeah, arduinoSerialData.readline() after write() kills the performance of the program...

Comment: try to clear the serial buffer after reading from the arduino, this will not kill the performance of the program